# Amazon S3 Explicit Deny with Liip Imagine Bundle resulting in 404

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, liipimaginebundle

**Background**

I'm trying to explicitly deny GET requests to assets in my S3 bucket unless the referrer is the actual site hosting them.  Many of these assets are cached images that are the result of Liip Imagine bundle filters (as well as the original uploaded images that these cached items stem from).

**Problem**

When I add the explicit deny statement in my bucket policy requests to those images do return 403, which is great, and many of the non cached images will load in the website under the correct domain, however attempts to resolve cached images using the Imagine bundle result in a 404.

**My Bucket Policy**

(domain and bucket obscured for privacy reasons)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://[MY_DOMAIN]/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ExplicitDenyReferer",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": "https://[MY_DOMAIN]/*"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**I've built this policy based on information here:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4

Looking in the inspector I can see that there is a media resolve request made as such:

- **Request Method:** https://[MY_DOMAIN]/media/cache/resolve/logo/main-logo.png
- **Status Code:** 404

In the Request Header:

- **authority:** [MY_DOMAIN]
- **method:** GET
- **path:** /media/cache/resolve/logo/main-logo.png
- **scheme:** https
- **referer:** https://[MY_DOMAIN]/

As soon as I remove the Explicit Deny statement in the Bucket policy, those images load fine.  I'm very confused as to why the 404.  I might expect a 403 with some sort of misconfiguration on my part, but 404 is unexpected.

I have verified the referrer in the request headers is exactly as it's entered in the Deny statement.

**Ultimately my questions are:**

- Why would this Deny statement result in a 404 of these media resolve
  requests?
- How can I make this work where the Imagine Bundle can create cached
  images from filter configurations, but yet deny requests to images
  that do not contain the correct referer?